# xsl:call-template by name stored in string

Tags: xslt

I have this xsl template:

```
<xsl:template name="test">
I'm test
</xsl:template>
```

and I can call this template by calling

```
<xsl:call-template name="test"/>
```

QUESTION:
How to call xsl template by name stored in variable?

```
<xsl:variable name="var1" select="'test'"/>
<xsl:call-template name="$var1"/>
```

Comment: I am not sure if things have changed in XSLT 3.0, but this is not possible in XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. You would probably have to use an `xsl:choose`,test each possible value of the variable and call the appropriate template. It may help if you explain what your underlying task is, as it might be possible to use a different approach that doesn't require dynamically calling templates. Thanks!

Comment: In addition to what Tim wrote, depending on the XSLT processor and version there might be XSLT/XPath 3 ways (higher-order functions, function variables, for simple cases just shadow attributes with static variables) or processor specific extensions (Saxon in 9.6 and earlier has `saxon:call-template`, see http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/xsl-elements/call-template.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `xsl:call-template`, try `xsl:apply-templates`.

```
<xsl:template name="test" match="test">
I'm test
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="var1"><test/></xsl:variable>

<xsl:apply-templates select="$var1/*"/>
```

But in XSLT 3.0 you can do this much more cleanly using higher-order functions; functions become first-class values and can be bound to variables.